# Different ordering of style tags negates other style tags

Tags: html, css, tags

So when I take the body background color tag and move it from the front of my style tags to the last style tag in the list my div.gallerycontainer all of a sudden does not work. Why would this happen? Seems like an absolute glitch. Here's the code:

Before:
-Black background color IS NOT set in the instance
-div.gallerycontainer style tag works in this instance

```
body{background-color: black;}

div.gallerycontainer{ 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 690px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

After
-Black background color IS in effect in this instance
-div.gallerycontainer style tag DOES NOT work in this instance

```
div.gallerycontainer{ 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 690px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body{background-color: black;}
```

Can't seem to make sense of a different ordering of style tags, changing the outcome of your site. I'm attempting to make an auto rotating image gallery from scratch with this code, have hardly started coding, but I've had similar issues like this in the past that seemed to magically disappear. Now that this issue is showing itself consistently it would be great to understand the issue and never have it again..

Nick P.

Comment: Negates other style tag* whoops*

Comment: Are you sure it's div.gallerycontainer that's not working? Or might it be some other conflict? Try to set up a jsfiddle for us to better know what's going on.

Comment: guys/gals, I'm noticing something QUITE strange in my IDE. Commented out notes in the form of : <-- This is a comment in notepadd++ --> WHEN removed allow my program to run just fine.. Maybe this is known issue but this is my first week of web stuff. Figuring that out feels like a miracle. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it must be some issue in your IDE, as you mentioned.

You can play around with it in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmknoll/dnuqdz17/

The ordering of your classes and elements in CSS shouldn't matter.

For this html:

```
<body>
    Some Text
</body>
<div class="gallerycontainer">
    Some Text
</div>
```

The two following sets of CSS should behave identically:

```
body{background-color: black;}

div.gallerycontainer{ 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 690px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

---

```
div.gallerycontainer{ 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 1030px;
  height: 690px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body{background-color: black;}
```